# How can I send video that I have recorded from one activity to another?

Tags: java, android, xml, android-studio

I am trying to send the video that I have recorded from one activity to another. I am thinking of sending the address but couldn't do so.

```
    public void startRecordingVideo(View view) {
    if (getPackageManager().hasSystemFeature(PackageManager.FEATURE_CAMERA_FRONT)) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_VIDEO_CAPTURE);
        File mediaFile = new File(
                Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + "/myvideo.mp4");
        videoUri = Uri.fromFile(mediaFile);
        intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, videoUri);
        startActivityForResult(intent, VIDEO_CAPTURE);
    } else {
        Toast.makeText(this, "No camera on device", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}
```

public void convert(View view){

```
    Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),convertVid.class);
    File mediaFile = new File(
            Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + "/myvideo.mp4");
    videoUri = Uri.fromFile(mediaFile);
    i.putExtra("video1",videoUri);
    startActivityForResult(i,1);
}
```

}

Comment: What does mean you couldn't? Do you have stacktrace? Are you sure you gave permission to write on external storage?

Comment: Why do you want to send video like that? Your video will be saved on external storage. You can access that video directly within another activity using its path..

Comment: Got it! this code works. But if you can tell me how to access the path it will be easier to manipulate the video for editing.